# writing an excel column using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl, pprint

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/sarahporgess/Desktop/SSA.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('SSA')

for row in range(2,sheet.max_row+1):
    for column in "ABC":
        #PROBLEM 1-only printing out one value, not the column
        date = sheet['A' +str(row)].value
        gamma = sheet['B' +str(row)].value
        theta = sheet['C' +str(row)].value

print(date)
print(gamma)
print(theta)

ratio = float(gamma)/float(theta)
print(ratio)
sheet['D1']=ratio


#3. Write to new sheet  
resultFile = open('SSS.csv', 'w')

#PROBLEM 2- The format of the file is off. 
resultFile.write(pprint.pformat(date))

resultFile.write(pprint.pformat(gamma))
resultFile.write(pprint.pformat(theta))    
resultFile.write( pprint.pformat(ratio))    
resultFile.close()
print('Done.')
```

The results I am getting is just the last cell value on the sheet, not the full column. here is what it prints:

```
2017-02-13 16:15:00

0.0022

-0.0021

-1.0476190476190477

Done.
```

Comment: can you properly format your code

Comment: Look at using `ws.iter_rows()` to get just the cells you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are overwriting your all variables like date,gamma and so on. so at the end of the loop, you will be having only last data so it is writing only last row.

I hope below code would work

`import openpyxl, pprint
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/sarahporgess/Desktop/SSA.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('SSA')
resultFile = open('SSS.csv', 'w')
for row in range(2,sheet.max_row+1):
    for column in "ABC":
        #PROBLEM 1-only printing out one value, not the column
        date = sheet['A' +str(row)].value
        gamma = sheet['B' +str(row)].value
        theta = sheet['C' +str(row)].value
        ratio = float(gamma)/float(theta)
        resultFile.write(pprint.pformat(date))
        resultFile.write(pprint.pformat(gamma))
        resultFile.write(pprint.pformat(theta))

        resultFile.write( pprint.pformat(ratio))
        print(ratio)
        sheet['D1']=ratio
resultFile.close()
print('Done.')`